# How i can make live streaming on my website

Tags: php, flash

I am a beginner of web programming trying to learn things. I am currently working on my own website where i am in need of live steaming for my friends and family. I have a Video Camera for capturing video. I want to get live stream on my website. I am capable to get the output on screen but i don't know how i can make my site able to live stream. My first question is whether it is possible? if yes then how i can achieve this goal. Any help regarding to my question will be appreciated highly. Thanks to the community of all web programmers.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest using a 3rd party streaming site like [livestream.com](http://www.livestream.com/), [ustream.tv](http://www.ustream.tv/), or [justin.tv](http://www.justin.tv/) since streams will eat up a lot of bandwidth, especially if you have a lot of watchers.

They will typically allow you to embed a flash video onto a web page to seamlessly integrate with your site.

Comment: Thanks tskuzzy for your help. if these resources are trustworthy. As i will only allow my registered users to view the live streaming. I have unlimited bandwidth so i think there will be no any issue of bandwidth. Is there any direct method of live streaming?

Comment: Even if it was "unlimited", your throughput is likely not high enough. Your server would be using ~400 kbs per user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can stream on website using [livestream.com](http://livestream.com) or [youtube.com](http://youtube.com) there are tons of software available in the market of this like 
**Deezer,
eMusic,
gogoyoko,
Grooveshark,
iLike,
Justin.tv (Allows to produce and watch live streaming video.),
Live365**
you can use them to solve your purpose..!!